# Using R to access Google Page Speed Insights

Tags: r, pagespeed

I found a script by a generous fellow on GitHub to access Page Speed Insights though R.

However his script is only pulling a handful of variables from the test.  I've looked all over for documentation can't find anything more.  Does anyone know how to pull more of the data that pagespeed provides?

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(gtools)

#' Speed results for 1 URL
#'
#' The speedfinder function returns the Google Page Speed Insights test results for a single URL as a dataframe.
#' speedfinder("https://www.cars.com","mobile",key)


speedfinder <- function(url,strategy,key) {
  pid <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=",url,"&strategy=",strategy,"&key=",key))
  frame1 <- cbind(as.data.frame(pid[2]),as.data.frame(pid[3]),as.data.frame(pid[5]),as.data.frame(pid[6]))
  rbind.data.frame(data.frame(), frame1,make.row.names=FALSE)
}



speedfinder2 <- function(url,strategy,key) {
  pid <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=",url,"&strategy=",strategy,"&key=",key))
  frame1 <- cbind(as.data.frame(pid[2]),as.data.frame(pid[3]),as.data.frame(pid[5]),as.data.frame(pid[6]))
}


speedlist <- function(pagelist,strategy,key) {
  list1 <- lapply(pagelist,speedfinder2,strategy,key)
  suppressWarnings(do.call("smartbind",list1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good description of the API on the Google PageSpeed Insights pages, and even a try-the-API sandbox or Explorer.  The fields mentioned there include:

url: The URL to fetch and analyze (string)

filter_third_party_resources:  Indicates if third party resources should be filtered out before PageSpeed analysis. (boolean)

locale: The locale used to localize formatted results (string)

rule:A PageSpeed rule to run; if none are given, all rules are run (string)

screenshot:Indicates if binary data containing a screenshot should be included (boolean)

strategy: The analysis strategy to use (string)

fields: Selector specifying which fields to include in a partial response.

I got that info from

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/pagespeedonline/v2/pagespeedonline.pagespeedapi.runpagespeed.

There's a broad overview at  https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/getting-started, which includes a link to a tutorial.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13883624)

Comment: Right you are!  Edited with some improvements.